# VideoView inside DialogFragment

Tags: android, border, android-videoview, android-dialogfragment

I just created a custom DialogFragment with a VideoView inside it and I get some problems with it.

- The video is playing, but for some strange reason, there is a kind of black and very transparent layer on the top of the video. Of course I tried to play this same video from somewhere else in my app which is not a dialog window, and it shows correctly. Very strange...
- Also, the top and left borders of the dialog window disappear - and if remove the VideoView, they don't.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Controller

```
public class VideoPlayerFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    String json_string;

    // Constructor
    public static VideoPlayerFragment newInstance(String json_string_arg)
    {
        VideoPlayerFragment fragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();

        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString("json_string", json_string_arg);
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);

        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set style
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_player, container, false);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

         // Set video holder
         VideoView video_view = (VideoView) getView().findViewById(R.id.video_view);

         // Set URL
         Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test);
         video_view.setVideoURI(video);

         // Start video
         video_view.start();
    }
}
```

View

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/video_player_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <VideoView android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="700dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put your dialog fragment code so that we can look what is prob

Comment: I really can't find the solution. Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
     public class VideoPlayerFragment extends DialogFragment
        {
            String json_string;

            // Constructor
            public static VideoPlayerFragment newInstance(String json_string_arg)
            {
                VideoPlayerFragment fragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();

                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString("json_string", json_string_arg);
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);

                return fragment;
            }

        @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                View parent= getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.video_player, null);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
dialog.setContentView(parent, layoutParams);
                return dialog;
            }
         @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                 // Set video holder
                 VideoView video_view = (VideoView) getView().findViewById(R.id.video_view);

                 // Set URL
                 Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test);
                 video_view.setVideoURI(video);

                 // Start video
                 video_view.start();
            }
```

Friend try the above code .Instead of creating the view try creating the onCreateDialog without dialog title ....

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same situation : videoview in DialogFragment.

issue 1 : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898766/1251276) may help you ,i just found it too;

issue 2 : I think you need these codes in method onActivityCreated() (this line hide the black border)

```
getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

ps:this is my init codes in onCreateView(,,)

```
if (getShowsDialog())
    {
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }
```